# Rails/Heroku: Could not detect rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, bundler

I'm facing an issue when trying to push my code to Heroku.
I don't understand why, I searched a lot and tried a lot of solution like adding "rake" as a Gem in the Gemfile, add linux and ruby platform to the lock file, install Gems with a lower bundler version, upgrading heroku buildpack, upgrading heroku stack, but none of these solved my issue.

When I push to Heroku, everything is doing good until bundle install phase, after this one, I get this error:

```
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rswag-specs-2.5.1/lib/rswag/specs.rb:3:in `<main>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rswag-2.5.1/lib/rswag.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.10/lib/bundler.rb:176:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:710:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7d354c0f/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
remote:  !
```

I hope someone has encountered the same problem and has the solution

Thanks

Comment: When you run `bundle exec rake -P` locally, what happens?

Comment: All rake commands are listed.

Comment: How about adding a production flag? `bundle exec rake -P RAILS_ENV=production`?